# Change file name in UIDocumentInteractionController when opening file in another app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uidocumentinteraction

I'm storing files in my application sandbox in a way that masks the original name of the file.

For example I have a file called abc.png which is stored in the sandbox as obfuscated.png.

When I do an open in of this file in another application using a UIDocumentInteractionController I'd like to have the other file open the file with the filename abc.png

Currently the other app opens the file as obfuscated.png.

I have tried changing the `name` property of the `UIDocumentInteractionController` in `documentInteractionControllerWillPresentOptionsMenu` as well as `willBeginSendingToApplication`, however in both cases the receiving application does not get the correct filename - it continues to show the obfuscated filename.

Apart from creating a copy of the file with the unobfuscated name, is there a way to make the receiving application use the desired filename?

Comment: I finally ended up creating a copy of the file in the willBeginSendingToApplication function and modifying the url property of the UIDocumentInteractionController

Comment: I am trying to do the same. I have 2 copies of the file, one is encrypted and another one is an original plain file. While previewing the file I am using plain file and while open-in I want to send the Encrypted file to the target app, but setting URL property doesn't help and it always sends plain version. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of a copy try:

```
NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] linkItemAtPath:obfuscatedFilePath toPath:abcFilePath error:&error];
```

This will create a hard link to the file. Symbolic links will not work.

Comment: This worked for me. I did this right before I created the UIDocumentInteractionController (not needing to use the delegate in my application).